# Difference between websphere MQ class for java vs Websphere MQ classes for JMS

Tags: ibm-mq, mq, xa

Can you please let me know what are difference between websphere MQ class for java vs Websphere MQ classes for JMS?

Which of the above should I use to connect to an IBM MQ client for performing distributed transactions (XA)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The JMS API is the JavaEE open standard for a messaging API. IBM MQ v8 now implements the latest version 2.0 JMS standard (MQ 8.0.0.2 has the JMS2.0 errata as well).

WMQ Java classes is a proprietary API to provide messaging; it's OO based around classic MQ objects, such as QueueManagers and Queues etc. There are some features such as support for MQ Multi-instance QMs and async call backs that it doesn't have.

**For any new application I would recommended that you use JMS**; if you encounter function that you really need that isn't in JMS please get in contact (RFE).

As to XA; what is the transaction co-coordinator that you wish to use? Via JMS  you can use a JavaEE server to do the XA co-ordination. Non JavaEE are not supported (though there is an RFE for thinks like Atomikos to be supported).

What is the scenario here? Is it full XA that is required or would a single phase transacted JMS Session be sufficient.

Via the Java Classes you can only co-ordinate messaging work via the MQ QM. DB2/Oracle can also be co-ordinated.

Comment: Thanx for the reply. I am currently using bitronix and want to preform distributed transaction on 1 db resource and 4 MQ's. My DB is currently XA compliant. My Queue Manager is not XA compliant so whenever i use com.ibm.mq.jms.MQXAConnectionFactory its failing. My client is worried about changing the setting of the Queue Manager installation and we wanted to see if there is any alternative. I am not able to find any valid resource online explaining how we can setup and connect to an XA compliant MQ client without changing the Queue Manager installation. Could you please help me out

Comment: a) The MQ QueueManager is inherently XA capable, as is the JMS Client libraries in use. There shouldn't be any change to the QM required

b) JMS is the API that you need to use here; but only JavaEE are currently supported by MQ JMS.  Transnational Integrity is paramount and we need to validate with other TxMgrs to ensure that a customer won't loose data. XA/JTA has a few 'gaps' that different vendors interpret differently,

(c) see https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/rfe/execute?use_case=viewRfe&CR_ID=36184  and get your client to use their IBM a/c team